# Ant design drawer header fixed

Tags: css, antd

Im using my react project for **[ant design drawer](https://3x.ant.design/components/drawer/)**, i have some conflict i tried drawer header fixed using  following **CSS** command `position:fixed` but its not appear , any one know some solution for this ?

**my code**

```
.ant-drawer-header {
    position: relative;
    padding: 16px 24px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    background: #fff;
    position:fixed;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Header is fix by default, You dont need to add position fixed.

Comment: @FatemehQasemkhani Hello there, no when i scroll my drawer header is hide

Comment: So share your code in sandbox or somewhere, and in your css style you have added both relative and fixed. why? if you want to add fixed position, you should add with 100% as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hear the solution

```
.ant-drawer-header {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 16px 24px;
  z-index: 99999;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  background: #fff;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
.ant-drawer-body {
   padding: 24px;
   margin-top: 3rem;
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 1.5;
   word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```